# find out the date from an input string

Tags: java

I am trying to find out the specific date from a given input string, which can be like "201411W3". I know that the week is 3rd from this string(W3) and the event will be on Friday, so I want to find the date of the 3rd Friday. I did something like this:

```
public static Date getLastFriday( int month, int year ) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set( year, month, 1 );
    cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, - ( cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) % 7 + 8 ) );
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

when I call this method: getLastFriday(11, 2014), I get the value "Fri Nov 21 13:16:57 EST 2014" which I need to parse to find out the date. is there any way to get just the date from the result?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need? A `Date` object that has zeros in the time fields? Or a string that simply says "Fri Nov 21". BTW, I think your method is incorrect (Try January 2014, which has 5 Fridays, it gives the 4th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, then you can use below code as reference -

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String str="201411W3";
        String[] strSplitted = str.split("W");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(strSplitted[0].substring(4,6))-1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(strSplitted[0].substring(0,4)));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==7)
        {
            calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(strSplitted[1])+1);
        }   
        else
        {
            calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(strSplitted[1]));
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime());

        System.out.println(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

`Output : 2014-11-21`  You can change the format to any format you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the month and day without the seconds, you could call `.get(Calendar.MONTH)` and `.get(Calendar.DATE)` and pass them into the constructor of a new date object and return that object.

More info: [here](http://www.java2s.com/Book/Java/0060__Development/Get_field_value_from_Calendar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) SimpleDateFormat

I didn't test the following code but it will work like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date myDate = sdf.parse("Fri Nov 21 13:16:57 EST 2014");
```